# Using nodejs google cloud logging library with user access token

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, bearer-token, google-cloud-logging

I'm trying to use the user token (`gcloud auth print-access-token`) to leverage getting logs using [@google-cloud/logging](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-logging).

Basic code snippet:

```js
import { GetEntriesResponse, Logging } from "@google-cloud/logging";

export async function readLogsAsync() {

  const logging = new Logging();

  const [entries, _, response]: GetEntriesResponse = await logging.getEntries({
    filter: 'resource.type="k8s_container"',
    resourceNames: 'projects/acme',
    autoPaginate: false,
    pageSize: 100
  });
  console.log(entries.length, response.nextPageToken)
}
```

Similar call in http works with the user token, so I'm assuming there must be some way to communicate it with the node.js api, but I couldn't find an example or documentation.

```bash
curl --location --request POST 'https://logging.googleapis.com/v2/entries:list?alt=json' \
--header "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)" \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "filter": "resource.type=\"k8s_container\"",
    "orderBy": "timestamp desc",
    "pageSize": 100,
    "resourceNames": [
        "projects/amce"
    ]
}'
```

Comment: did you perform a `gcloud auth application-default login`?

Comment: Why are you using the HTTP method POST? The API uses GET. https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/projects.logs/list

Answer (score 1):

You're not authenticating the code.

Google's libraries support a mechanism called [Application Default Credentials (ADC)](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production).

ADC makes it easy to authenticate code deployed to Google Cloud Platform and when running locally. To run locally, you will need to export `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` with the path to a Service Account key.

As @guillaume-blaquiere comments, you can effect this behavior using `gcloud auth application-default` but it is better to use a Service Account.

Comment: Indeed, but why use service account when I already got a user session? I don't mind security concerns, only ease of use for the code

Comment: Google discourages the `application-default` mechanism. The User credentials that are obtained for it include all the permissions of your user account including access to the account's user's data. Using a Service Account is more precise. But, do what you want.